How to use MSTest to test a C# async method where it doesn't complete until I feed it more data?
I'm writing unit tests where the SUT is a queue; the language is C#, and I'm using the MSTest framework.  One method in the queue, async Task<int[]> DequeueAsync(int count), waits until the queue contains enough items before returning the requested number of them in an array.  I want to verify that if I call DequeueAsync() requesting n+k items but the queue presently only contains n items, the method will wait until I enqueue at least k more items before returning the result.  So, for example, I might call DequeAsync(count: 10) when there are only four items in the queue, and then enqueue another six items so that there are now ten items in the queue, allowing DequeueAsync() to return.  But if I use await, won't the task block, preventing me from feeding the additional six items to the queue? How can I start the task and then do the other stuff the task relies upon to complete?
I have successfully tested the method when there are sufficient items in the queue to immediately return the requested number, but I don't have any idea how to test the scenario where I call the method and then resume execution so I can do additional stuff the method requires before it will return.

If your producer can be Moq-ed you can use the Sequential calls setup: https://github.com/devlooped/moq/wiki/Quickstart#miscellaneous

Yes, the task awaiting on  DequeueAsync() will block. That's the idea. If you use two or more tasks (or explicit threads, etc), inserting more elements will be the job of another task.

Actually, the await blocks in this way: the lines following the await won't be executed until the awaited task ends. But the execution flow (of the current thread) will be immediately passed back to the function calling the function that issued the await (except when this call is also awaited). So, this works as a form of concurrent execution, and you could still insert into the queue while awaiting on the DequeueAsync(), depending on your exact code. This scenario may be too complex for what you're looking for.

The other option is not to await the DequeueAsync() and just go on with your operations, alternating between adding elements to the queue and checking the status of the dequeuing (asynchronous) task.

As I understand it, you've designed a queue similar to this class that I made to try and reproduce your issue.
public class QueueThatWaitsForN<T> : Queue<T>
{
    object _criticalSection = new object();
    public async Task<T[]> DequeueAsync(int n, int pollingMs = 100, CancellationToken? token = null)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (token is CancellationToken valid)
            {
                if (valid.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // Return empty or partial contents.
                    return localDequeueN();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int captureCount;
                lock (_criticalSection)
                {
                    captureCount = Count;
                }
                if (captureCount >= n)
                {
                    return localDequeueN();
                }
                await Task.Delay(Math.Max(10, pollingMs));
            }
        }
        T[] localDequeueN()
        {
            var builder = new List<T>();
            lock (_criticalSection)
            {
                while (Count > 0 && builder.Count < n)
                {
                    builder.Add(Dequeue());
                }
                return builder.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }    
    public new void Enqueue(T t)
    {
        lock (_criticalSection)
        {
            base.Enqueue(t);
        }
    }
}



And your question is:

how to test the scenario where I call the method and then resume execution so I can do additional stuff the method requires before it will return.

In other words, you're trying to await your SUT and then supply it with some data to enqueue, but if you're blocked awaiting the dequeue then how can you supply the data that would ever make it resume execution from the await?
It may seem counterintuitive, but the Task that is going to populate your SUT needs to be started before any awaits that you perform on it. Here's how that might look:
[TestMethod("Asynchronous test of Queue N")]
public async Task TestQueueN()
{
    Random
        randoDelay = new Random(),
        randoLength = new Random(Seed:1);
    object randoLock = new object();
    var SUT = new QueueThatWaitsForN<char>();
    int testValue = 0;
    bool isCanceled = false;
    Task? loop = null;
    var output = new StringBuilder();
    output.AppendLine(); // cosmetic to make the limit left-aligned
    try
    {
        loop = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!isCanceled)
            {
                await Task.Delay(randoDelay.Next(1, 10));
                SUT.Enqueue($"{testValue++}".Last());
            }
        });
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { }
    const int NLOOP = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < NLOOP; i++)
    {
        int limit;
        lock (randoLock)
        {
            limit = randoLength.Next(5, 25);
        }
        var result = await SUT.DequeueAsync(limit);
        var line = $"Requested: {limit} Received: {string.Join(string.Empty, result)}";
        output.AppendLine(line);
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        Assert.AreEqual(
            expected: limit,
            actual: result.Length,
            $"Expecting queue to wait for {limit}");
    }
    isCanceled = true;
    if (loop is not null) await loop.WaitAsync(timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    Assert.AreEqual(
        expected: @"
Requested: 9 Received: 012345678
Requested: 7 Received: 9012345
Requested: 14 Received: 67890123456789
Requested: 20 Received: 01234567890123456789
Requested: 18 Received: 012345678901234567
Requested: 13 Received: 8901234567890
Requested: 12 Received: 123456789012
Requested: 23 Received: 34567890123456789012345
Requested: 7 Received: 6789012
Requested: 17 Received: 34567890123456789
",
        actual: output.ToString(),
        "Expecting pseudorandom output to match because of (Seed:1)");
    { }
}


